# Power series in complex analysis

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

We derived from cauchy's integral formula that a holomorphic function converges locally in a power series. Now we had the [Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) and I wanted to know whether I can conclude from this that the power series of a function is uniquely determined and converges on the whole domain of the function(which should be assumed to be connted and open) and not just locally anymore?

Comment: Whole domain? Is it circular?

Comment: no, just an open set

Comment: If a power series converges absolutely at $x=a$ then it also converges on all the circle $x=e^{i\theta}a$.

Comment: i guess this does not answer my question. the question is: if i have a given function f that is holomorphic and defined on some open set $U$, is there, after the theorems I pointed out in my question, a unique power series of this function which converges on $U$?

Comment: I wasn't answering your question. Just making you think. If the power series must converge (absolutely) in a disc, and $U$ is not a disc, then convergence in $U$ is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. It is analytic in $\mathbb C - \{0\}$. This function can't be expressed as a power series on its entire domain of definition, for the following reason. Suppose $f$ is given as a power series expansion at $z=0$. This is impossible, since such a power series can be extended to $z=0$, while the function $f(z)$ has an essential discontinuity at $z=0$. So, suppose $f$ is given as a power series expansion about $z=z_0\ne 0$. The assumption is thus that the power series converges for every $w\ne 0$, and that it gives $f(w)$. But then the radius of convergence of the power series is $\infty $, and thus, again, the function $f(z)$ should be extendable to $z=0$, which is false.

Comment: thank you, are there also counterexamples if we assume that the domain is connected and open?

Comment: @Lipschitz to domain above is open and connected.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly not. Consider the function $1/(1-z)$, analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$. Its power-series expansion at $0$ is $1+z+z^2+\cdots\,$, which isn’t convergent on the unit circle at all, nor, of course, beyond that.

Comment: so the best thing we can get in complex analysis is that an analytic function can be represented locally with a power series? sorry I should ask about connected open sets, since that is what the identity theorem talks about